# SwiftUI Popover background with Material

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, popover

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI Popover with a translucent material(regular, thin, or ultra-thin) background. To show up some vibrancy of the content behind the Popover content.

I tried adding `ultraThin` and other material types to the background view. they don't have any effect on the popover background. Also tried creating a `UIViewRepresentable` by creating a visual effect view. Still, there's no effect on the popover background.

```
   .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                            ZStack {
                                Text("My popover content")
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        }
```

Comment: use [this](https://github.com/aheze/Popovers) library, it is pretty good

Comment: This library may bring down the heavy lifting of popovers, but may not solve the actual issue.

Comment: The `.popoverTip()` actually has a translucent background, maybe that can be used. Probably not a great solution though (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## iOS 16.4+

iOS 16.4 introduced a new `.presentationBackground()` modifier that can be used to set a background material to a popover or a modal presented view. Just pass the material you want to use as a parameter.

```swift
.popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .presentationBackground(.regularMaterial)
}
```

Make sure to use the `presentationBakcground()` modifier **inside** the `.sheet()` or `.popover()` closure. More documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackground(_:)).

## Older versions

Popovers are by default translucent on iPadOS and macOS. On iOS, popovers are presented in the form of a modal view.

The `.background(.ultraThinMaterial)` is applied directly on your ZStack view but not on the popover/modal view itself. Using `UIViewRepresentable` or `UIViewControllerRepresentable` will only wrap your UIView/UIViewController inside a View and will still have no effect on the popover/modal.

At that time (SwiftUI 4, Xcode 14.2), it is not possible to change the background material of a popover/modal view using SwiftUI.

Comment: Yeah, when we inspect the UI from Xcode View Debugger, there are many layers under the popover, over which we don't have any direct control.